# uiwebview interrupt vs error

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an UIWebView in my iOS app, which displays a very long web page. If the page fails to load for some reason, I display an alert in my webView:didFailLoadWithError: method. However, it is possible that user would tap some link BEFORE the page is fully loaded, and UIWebView treats that as an error as well, which I want to ignore silently. Is there any way to find out that a page loading error originates from user tapping a link?

Comment: Just a quick thought that comes to mind....what if you just disable the webview and enable it at `webViewDidFinishLoad:`?

Comment: Yeah, that is my "last resort" option — to make the UI unresponsive for a while. That would be less damaging then confusing the user with the wrong error message, but still bad.

Comment: Well if you do go with that, you could probably place some sort of loading indicator in the middle of the screen so the user knows somethings happening.

Comment: If you want to ignore it, you can have a look at the error codes of the `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` errors. I suspect that the error code for the "tap link before page is fully loaded" would be different to the others so just use `if([error code] == {figure out what the code is for that case by NSLog(@"error: %@")}) return; `

Comment: Oh, yes, stupid me. It's NSURLErrorCancelled, which seems to be safe to ignore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user1135469 suggested, error.code seems to be the key. It's NSURLErrorCancelled when the user taps the link, and it's safe to just ignore this error code.